# Special characters in JavaScript comments

Tags: javascript, comments, character, special-characters

I want to embed a cheat code into the comments of a JavaScript file. It's an [Easter egg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Easter_egg#Noun) if people view the source. Will these special characters (the arrows) be a problem for JavaScript interpreters?

```
/*
 ( " ↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A ENTER " )
*/
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you load this into your browser? Select it, copy it, press F12, navigate to your console, paste it, run it. Profit ;)

Comment: Ha cheers. It works but I have only tested on modern browsers. Just want someone to elucidate Javascript's support for these types of characters.

Comment: I dare to say as long as you don't have an instance of `*/` or `/*` in your comment, you're safe.

Comment: @JonathanSampson that's what I assumed too.

Comment: worst case scenario, just type up up down down left right left right b a enter.. or konami cheat code... anybody smart enough to view source is smart enough to figure out the rest

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'll leave open if anyone has any information on characters that JS can handle

Comment: It’s worth noting that something like jsLint might hurt your feelings over this, but I wouldn’t be too concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s safe. Within a comment, any characters can be used, except those recognized as terminating a comment by the language specification. By the ECMAScript standard, a comment may contain any Unicode code unit, and there is no reason to suspect that implementations fail to obey this (they just need to skip all character data there, recognizing only comment termination).

However, a user viewing a .js file may or may not see the characters correctly, depending on the character encoding settings. You cannot guarantee this, but you can help with it by serving .js files from the server with `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8` (if your file is UTF-8 encoded, as it most probably is in this case) and by using the attribute `charset=utf-8` in the `script` element that refers to the file. Oh, and use UTF-8 with BOM.

Even if the encoding issue is handled properly, there is the possibility that the program used for viewing the .js file uses a font that does not contain the character you have in the comment, so they won’t be seen by the peeking visitor. But this does not affect functionality.

Comment: Re *"...terminating a comment "*: But not *starting* a new (nested) comment?

Comment: Peter, you cannot nest comments. When a comment has been started with “/*, then any “/*” pair will be treated just as characters inside the comment.